# How to test that a Stack has elements in Ruby and rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following specs for my Stack module:

```
describe Stack do
  let(:stackable_obj) { (Class.new { include Stack }).new }

  describe '#stack' do
    context 'when it has no elements' do
      it 'is an empty array' do 
        expect(stackable_obj.stack).to eq([])
      end
    end
  end
  ..
end
```

And I fail to see how would I test that the stack returns element when it is not empty. My module looks like this:

```
module Stack
  def stack
    @stack ||= []
  end
end
```

Would I mock the stack method? I have done this:

```
context 'when it has elements' do
  it 'gives an array with the elements' do 
    allow(stackable_obj).to receive(:stack).and_return([1,2,3])
    expect(stackable_obj.stack).to eq([1,2,3])
  end
end
```

But somehow seems like a useless test, because I am actually mocking the method that I am testing.

Comment: Decide how you want the caller to push an object on to the stack, implement that method, then use it in your test.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the stubbing for your `it 'gives an array with the elements'` test case is one level too high.  You want to make sure that calling `stackable_obj.stack` returns you the value contained in `stackable_obj`'s `@stack` instance variable when one is present, so the value of `@stack` is what I think you want to stub:

```
context 'when it has elements' do
  it 'gives an array with the elements' do 
    stackable_obj.instance_variable_set(:@stack, [1,2,3])
    expect(stackable_obj.stack).to eq([1,2,3])
  end
end
```